# Python: como validar quantos arquivos tenho em uma pasta e enviar por e-mail

Tags: python, python-3.x

Boa tarde, tudo bem?

Estou com uma duvida em meu código python, estou tentando fazer uma automatização de envio de e-mails com arquivos específicos, esses e-mails eu envio diariamente e são e-mails aleatórios com anexos aleatórios, as vezes tem 15 arquivos que vão para 15 e-mails diferentes e tem vezes que tem 20 arquivos que vão para e-mails diferentes, depende o dia.
Minha duvida está em como validar quantos arquivos tem na pasta naquele dia especifico e como parametrizar para qual e-mail ele será mandado. Estudando ao longo do dia criei um código que valida se o arquivo com o nome especifico existe ou não, se ele existir, ele troca o nome do arquivo pelo e-mail da pessoa que será mandado e assim manda por e-mail, dessa forma ele funciona, porém, tem mais 15 e-mails para fazer isso e esse numero de e-mail é aleatório as vezes são 15,16,17,18 arquivos para enviar no dia. alguém poderia me ajudar? obs(cada arquivo tem um nome padrão, por exemplo teste1, teste2 e teste3, tenho uma lista com os e-mails definido para quem eu preciso mandar o teste1, teste2 e teste3).

```
import os
import win32com.client as win32
import time
from pathlib import Path
import os.path


if(os.path.exists(r'C:\Users\Desktop\convenios\teste1.txt')):
  print("O arquivo existe")
else:
  print("O arquivo não existe")



os.rename (r'C:\Users\Desktop\convenios\teste1.txt',r'C:\Users\Desktop\convenios2\joao@hotmail.com.txt')

#Informações do e-mail
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')

folder = Path(r"C:\Users\Desktop\convenios2")

#leitura documentos em anexo
for attachment in folder.iterdir():
    #envio de e-mail
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.SentOnBehalfOfName = 'joao@hotmail.com.br'
    mail.HTMLBody = """
    <p>Olá,</p>
    <p>Segue documentos em anexo!</p>
    <p>Atenciosamente.</p>
    <p>João</p>"""
    mail.Attachments.Add(str(attachment))
    # coloca o nome do arquivo, sem a extnsão, como endereço do email antes do "@"
    mail.To = f'{attachment.stem}'
    #mail.Subject = str(attachment)
    mail.subject = ('arquivo teste')
    mail.display()
    time.sleep(5)
    mail.Send()
    print ("email enviado com sucesso!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom para obter os arquivos da pasta basta usar o  `dir = os.listdir('local onde os arquivos estão')` o valor retornado vai ser uma lista com todos arquivos
após isso basta apenas criar um laço de repetição para cada arquivo

segue exemplo:

```
pasta_emails = os.listdir("local da Pasta")
for email in pasta_emails:
    print(email)
```

se quiser fazer usando `while` você terá que ter parâmetros para quebra do laço

vide exemplo:

```
pasta_emails = os.listdir("local da Pasta")

quantidade_arquivos_na_pasta = len(pasta_emails) - 1
contador = 0

while contador != quantidade_arquivos_na_pasta:
   #obter nome do arquivo
   print(pasta_emails[contador])
   contador +=1
```

no caso o primeiro passo é pegar todos arquivos que estão na pasta em que você salva seu email.

usando a função built-in `len()` e usando como parâmetro a lista retornada com os nomes do arquivos você obtém a quantidade de itens que tem na lista. (nesse caso eu subtrai 1 pois a função `len()` conta apartir do 1 e a primeira posição nas listas chamamos por 0)

após isso já tem o parâmetro para definir quando o `while` deve ser interrompido

espero ter ajudado, bons estudos

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Kelvin!´

Comment: Qualquer coisa se não ficar claro só me falar por aqui que tento ajudar

Comment: Show mano, só tenho mais uma duvida, estou estudando a estrutura de repetição while, só que não estou conseguindo imaginar como faço para validar o arquivo. exemplo:                                      no dia de hoje tem 15 arquivos, como que eu faria para ele saber que são 15 arquivos e os 15 são para o e-mail especifico, ai no dia de amanhã tenho 16 arquivos e ele precisa adicionar mais 1 e-mail, isso automaticamente, entende?

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta para exemplificar melhor

Comment: Kelvin, a alteração funcionou muito obrigado!

Comment: kelvin, está por ai?

Comment: Bom dia Gabriel, acredito se for alguma duvida, cria uma pergunta que ja respondo assim que você abrir

Comment: show, se puder dar uma força ;-;